# unable to mount lvm partition

Tags: partitioning, mount, lvm

Hi I am trying to mount a new Logical volume. I am on ubuntu server 13.04. I have created the lv using the rest of the disk space. I am receiving this error :

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/mapper/TheServer--vg-lv_media': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/mapper/TheServer--vg-lv_media' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Im not sure why this is occuring. here is a list of my LVM setup:

```
--- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/TheServer-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                TheServer-vg
  LV UUID                OVIFDE-jtqA-lvlm-3Qu2-mWz9-Ktsw-IjlFdb
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time TheServer, 2013-05-08 19:26:34 -0600
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                26.30 GiB
  Current LE             6734
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/TheServer-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                TheServer-vg
  LV UUID                bGmvaC-Q2xf-V814-TG7i-9mDp-XJv3-CI0rVA
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time TheServer, 2013-05-08 19:26:35 -0600
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                3.50 GiB
  Current LE             895
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/TheServer-vg/lv_media
  LV Name                lv_media
  VG Name                TheServer-vg
  LV UUID                OK3auK-I1sL-DiBf-sYxV-gZFs-UfOR-OcNDDA
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time theserver, 2013-05-20 23:09:29 -0600
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                901.47 GiB
  Current LE             230776
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:2
```

I am mounting to `/media/store`

could this be an issue because the mount point is on another LV in the same VG ?

Comment: To have a mount point on another LV is not a problem. Actually it seems like it has no valid file system. Is it a newly created LV set? Only the lv_media is unmountable?

Comment: this is a fairly new server, so yes this is a new LV set. and I assume the lv_media is the only one that is unmountable because the root lv is my root directory and the server is running with no issues.

Comment: Have you created any type of filesystem on lv_media with `mkfs` or any other tool?

Comment: no I have not created any filesystem using any tools

Answer (score 1):

Creating a partition alone doesn't make it usable, it's necessary to make a filesystem on it. You need to do it the same way with an LVM partition just as with a simple partition. The tool to use is the `mkfs` with the proper parameters. Specifying the filesystem type and the device name will suffice. If you want to create an `ext4` type filesystem, this will work:

`sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/TheServer-vg/lv_media`

Similarly substitute `ext4` with other filesystem type if you like, though the `[TAB]` key will help as usual.